# how can I verify that each row of a table is associated with at least one row of another table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqlcheck

I'm trying to verify that in a table of my DB each row is associated with at least one row of another table.

In particular I have these 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS coltraneShop.Personage (
  `Name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT PK_Personage PRIMARY KEY (`Name`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS coltraneShop.`Product_Personage` (
  `Product code` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Personage's name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT PK_Product_Personage PRIMARY KEY (`Product code`, `Personage's name`)
);
ALTER TABLE coltraneShop.`Product_Personage` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_ProductPersonage_Personage` FOREIGN KEY (`Personage's name`) REFERENCES coltraneShop.Personage(`Name`)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS coltraneShop.Product (
  `Product code` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Category` CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
  CHECK(`Category`="DVD" OR `Category`='Album' OR `Category`='Comics' OR `Category`='Book' OR `Category`='Videogame'),
  `Title` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `Quantity` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  CHECK(`Quantity` BETWEEN 000 AND 999),
  `Year of publication` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  CHECK(`Year of publication` BETWEEN 0000 AND 9999), 
  `Price` DECIMAL(6,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Shipment's name` CHAR(13) NOT NULL, 

  CHECK(
    (SELECT count(*)
    FROM coltraneShop.Product_Personage AS PP
    WHERE `Category`= "Comics" AND PP.`Product code` = `Product code`) >= 1
),

CONSTRAINT PK_Product PRIMARY KEY (`Product code`)
);
ALTER TABLE coltraneShop.Product ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_Product_Shipment` FOREIGN KEY(`Shipment's name`) REFERENCES coltraneShop.Shipment(`Name`)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE coltraneShop.`Product_Personage` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_ProductPersonage_Product` FOREIGN KEY (`Product code`) REFERENCES coltraneShop.Product(`Product code`)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

OK! So, the table "Product_Personage" expresses a many-to-many relationship between product and personage. 
I want to check that if a row in the product table has the "category" attribute set to "Comics" then this product must appear at least once in the Product_Personage table.

In the code I left what seems to me to be correct to do in the product table. That is CHECK.

I'm using MySQL and when execute this code I get an error that is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS coltraneShop.Product (     `Product code` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Category` CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
 CHECK(`Category`="DVD" OR `Category`='Album' OR `Category`='Comics' OR `Category`='Book' OR `Category`='Videogame'),     `Title` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 `Quantity` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 CHECK(`Quantity` BETWEEN 000 AND 999),
 `Year of publication` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 CHECK(`Year of publication` BETWEEN 0000 AND 9999),
  `Price` DECIMAL(6,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 `Shipment's name` CHAR(13) NOT NULL,
   CHECK(         (SELECT count(*)         FROM coltraneShop.Product_Personage AS PP         WHERE `Category`= "Comics" AND PP.`Product code` = `Product code`) >= 1     ),      
CONSTRAINT PK_Product PRIMARY KEY (`Product code`) )

Error Code: 3815. An expression of a check constraint 'Product_chk_4' contains disallowed function.
```

Does it make sense to do such a check, and if so is it correct to write it as I did?
Thanks to all!

Comment: You can use ForeignKey Constraints

Comment: Where? I already use a FK constraint from Personage_Product table to Product table but that's not enough or am I wrong? Because if I add a product with category= "Comics" and nothing in Personage and in Personage_Product, it is correct for the DB but isn't correct for what I want to do. Because I want that if there is a product with Category = "Comics" there must be at least one Personage associated to this product in Personage_Product table.

Comment: Assuming you implement this check somehow (eg. with a trigger). You can't insert a new product with `category = 'comics'`, before it's already referenced in the `Product_Personage` table. And you can't reference it before you insert it. Or your question is too confusing.

Answer (score 1):

As in the mysql manual  stated

```
 Stored functions and user-defined functions are not permitted.

Stored procedure and function parameters are not permitted.

Variables (system variables, user-defined variables,
 and stored program local variables) are not permitted.

Subqueries are not permitted.
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html

that is why

```
 CHECK((SELECT count(*) FROM coltraneShop.Product_Personage AS PP
     WHERE `Category`= "Comics" AND PP.`Product code` = `Product code`) >= 1),
```

fails.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was going crazy without finding anything. So I understand that I have no way to verify this in any way?

Comment: You get an error Message, by using foreign keys, when the id doesn't exist if the reference is the id of the table, so you cannot add a row without having a valid Product_Personage